# Prove that $\vert P\cap N\vert = p^b$ and $\vert PN/N\vert=p^{a-b}$

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $G$ be a group of order $p^{a}m$ where $p$ does not divide $m$. Assume $P$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^a$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{b}n$ where $p$ does not divide $n$.
>
> Prove that $\vert P\cap N\vert = p^b$ and $\vert PN/N\vert=p^{a-b}$

So I know that since $N$ is normal in $G$ and $P$ is a subgroup that $PN$ is a subgroup of $G$.
And I know that $P\cap N\trianglelefteq N$ and $P\cap N\trianglelefteq P$.

So then $\vert P\cap N\vert$ divides the order of $P$

Thus $\vert P\cap N\vert=p^c$

Then I want to find $\vert N:P\cap N\vert$

Since $P\cap N$ is normal in $N$ its cosets partition $N$

I want to prove there must be $n$ cosets so that $c=b$

I know there must be at least $n$ but I don't see why there can't be $p^dn$ where $p^b=p^{c+d}$

After proving that then I can show the rest.

Since if $\vert N:P\cap N\vert=n$ then $\vert P\cap N\vert = p^b$ and I get that

$PN/N\cong P/P\cap N$ by second isomorphism theorem. which shows $\vert PN/N\vert = p^{a-b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Second Isomorphism Theorem:
$$|PN| = \frac{|P||N|}{|P \cap N|} $$
You can observe that $P$ and $N$ are subgroups of $PN$. Thus, by Lagrange's Theorem, $p^an \mid |PN|$. We can also observe that from above, $|PN|$ divides $|P||N|=p^{a+b}n$. Finally, by Lagrange's Theorem once again, we have $|PN|$ divides $|G|=p^am$. These three conclude that $|PN|=p^an$. Substitution yields $|P \cap N|=p^b$.

Comment: I don't understand the last use of Lagrange. I get that $\vert PN\vert=p^a nk $ form the first step, but after that I'm not sure how you get it equals $p^an$

Comment: Alright, so once you take $|PN|=p^ank$, we have shown that this value divides $p^{a+b}n$. This means that $k \mid p^b$. We also know that $p^ank$ must divide $p^am$ and thus $k \mid m$. From both of these, $k \mid \gcd(p^b,m)$. This GCD is $1$ since $p \nmid m$ and thus, $k=1$.